# What's the difference between the terms "gene map" and "genome"?

Tags: genetics, dna, dna-sequencing, genomics, genomes

It seems some sites arbitrarily restrict "gene map" to only a single chromosome, but others don't. Supposing we don't restrict it to just a single chromosome, is it different from "genome"? Are these two terms just synonyms?

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Please indicate your sources when posting questions of this type. We need links to example sites and text citations to clear up possible misunderstandings. (You should also read how to ask a good question in the [Help](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) — "Search and Research".)

Answer (score 2):

This question can be easily answered by reference to reputable sources on the internet, but as it is important to encourage the general use of the term, Genome, I shall cite examples.

**Genome**

> WHAT IS A GENOME?
>
> A genome is an organism’s complete set of DNA, including all of its genes

*[US National Library of Medicine, Genetics Home Reference](https://ghr.nlm.nih.gov/primer/hgp/genome)*

**Genetic Map**

> the arrangement of genes on a chromosome

*[Merriam Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/map)*

This is actually *definition 3 of map* in the dictionary — i.e. a variant on topological maps. The scientific usage is made clearer in the following:

**Mapping**

> DNA mapping refers to the variety of different methods that can be used to describe the positions of genes. DNA maps can show different levels of detail, similar to topological maps of a country or city, to indicate how far two genes are located from one another.

*[Nature Scitable](https://www.nature.com/scitable/definition/mapping-282/)*

**Distinction in a nutshell**

A *Genome* is an entity — a *Genetic Map* is a graphical representation of features of that entity.

Hence the following sentence makes sense:

> There is no genetic map for the genome of *Bacillus obscurus*.

The two terms are certainly **not** identical. The confusion of the poster may relate to the practical limitations of representation such that often the map of only one chromosome is presented at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Gene map is the spatial arrangement of genetic markers and the relative distance between each of them. While the genome includes the entire hereditary information of the organism; this includes both genes and the non-coding sequences of DNA (introns).